# about library implementations

Tags: c++

When I am reading the book exceptional c++, the following sentence causes my confusion:
"...because library implementations are allowed to do things like add their own extra template parameters (beyond those required by the standard), which, of course, your code wouldn't know about—one of the primary reasons for the rule that programmers aren't allowed to write their own declarations for things in namespace std."

**So what does it mean when it says add their own extra template parameters we can't see?**

Is it the reason why I only see

```
typedef basic_string<char>    string;
```

in the qt std::string implementation but without specifying the  _Traits template variable. However, the comment in the file says the defaults value of _Traits is char_Traits. I search the entire file but still do not find how the library set the default value for the _traits variable. So I wondering is it related to the sentence that causes my confusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementations of the standard library must provide the features that are described in the standard, but they can add extensions. Of course, these extensions must not conflict with programs that were written with just the standard in mind. In other words, the standard is a lower limit that must be achieved.

Now, concerning your confusion about `std::string`, this is defined as `std::basic_string<char>`. However, the `basic_string` class template has more than one template parameter, but for the other parameters there are defaults (which in turn depend on the first parameter). I'm pretty sure that you can find them, even if that isn't really easy as the typical library code is not written with readability but standard conformance in mind (which is the reason for the many `_Foo` names).

Comment: so you mean two other parameters for the basic_string is defined according to the first parameters?

Comment: Yes. From the back of my head, it's something like `basic_string<char_type, char_traits=traits<char_type>, allocator_type=allocator<char> >`.

Comment: While it is stated in the standard that the implementation can add additional template arguments, different constrains on the standard may inhibit an implementation from doing so. This is not a clear black and white thing. This answer **does** explain what the quote is about (+1), the concern is whether the quote is really true or not...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas  so how can I prove the quote is from the book?

Comment: @user2984297: I am not arguing the fact that the author states that in the book, but I am not sure that his statement is true.